# BizTalk 2006 with WebSphere MQ 7.0

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq, biztalk-2006

Does anyone know if BizTalk 2006 MQSeries adapter (server version) supports MQ 7.0 on W2k3? I know R2 does but none of the documentation specifically mentions it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely WMQ perspective, the answer is "yes."  IBM has published a [support statement](http://bit.ly/foec9N) that WMQ Server V7 is compatible with all previous WMQ clients.  Assuming the BizTalk 2006 client is either bundling the IBM client or at least is compatible with it, then it should work fine.